# ASP.NET MVC - user managment of folder with pictures (FTP?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am developing an ASP.NET MVC application and I need a per-user folder with images (including subfolders). I am looking for an easy way to allow managment of such image galerries (folder upload, single image upload, delete, display).

The galery itself isnt the key function of the application and doesnt have to be fancy (no need for comments etc.)

Right now, I am thinking about FTP account for each user. However,

1. Is there a way to set size limits from c# code to ftp folder?
2. How would "normal user" upload his image folders? Is there any free plugin wrapping up FTP picture managment?

Or is there a more simpler way?

Comment: Hi @Tomas. Each user will have its own folder, do they upload and download? i understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, each user has own folder and can manage it how he wants. In addition to download, a overview of image thumbnails would be nice.

Comment: .Net Membership may be good to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the size of a folder, use code

Vb.Net

```
Dim Klasor As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content"))
Dim Boyut As Decimal
For Each dr In Klasor.GetFiles
   Boyut += dr.Length
Next
```

Vb to C# :(

```
DirectoryInfo Klasor = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content"));
    decimal Boyut = default(decimal);
    foreach (object dr_loopVariable in Klasor.GetFiles) {
        dr = dr_loopVariable;
        Boyut += dr.Length;
    }
```

Close access to folders on http, Use authorizations membership. Query only accept members own folder. Use authorization to read and write operations..

Sample read : Vb.Net

```
    Function FileReturn() As FileResult
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/{UserID}/me.png"))
            Return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png") 
//and for download Return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png").FileDownloadName("me.png download") or Return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png","meee")
        End Function
```

Convert C# :

```
public FileResult FileReturn()
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/{UserID}/me.png"));
    return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png");
    //and for download Return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png").FileDownloadName("me.png download") or Return File(fi.OpenRead, "image/png","meee")
}
```

I'm sorry for vb.net code

Comment: @Tomas, If you are wondering as Logic, is about a full synchronization use client application. Sample Dropbox or Google Drive. In the code you're asking, I do not have an example of